# Why ActiveRecord caches find(:all) between requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, caching, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have this in my controller:

```
def frontpage
  @sections = Section.all
end
```

In production environment, the query seems to be cached between requests. Until I restart an app, `@sections` is always the same. Why and how do I fix this? I should also mention, I use Postgres in production, could it be the reason?

Comment: How are you determining that the query is cached?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in your production environment, you have enabled caching somewhere. While I'm not able to tell you why and where, I can give you a solution:

```
def frontpage
    uncached do
        @sections = find(:all)
    end
end
```

At least it should do the trick

e: The benefit of this, is that it only affects the code inside the block. Everything else should still get cached.

Answer (score 0):

Queries are not cached between requests, but actions could be. Do you have `cache_action` or other caching mechanism defined in your controller?

EDIT: to figure out if it's your action that's being cached, put this in your action:

```
def frontpage
  return render :text => Time.now.to_s
  ...
end
```

And see it it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462950/765357) from a related question. If your configuration is set up to cache, then you should switch that off (in development at least.) Otherwise, if you want to invalidate the cache of a specific page, you can look into defining a method to do so in your controller:

```
private
def invalidate_cache
     Rails.cache.delete("/sections")
end
```

You would need to specify when that is called, but it would do the trick.