# Rails assets are cached even in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Here is my Development.rb file

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
```

For some reason even in the development environment my CSS files are being cached and I can't figure out why

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462889/ruby-on-rails-clear-a-cached-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was having similar issue: Javascript files were cached by the rails server

Solution (as mentioned by TheIrishGuy):

1. Stop Rails Server
2. $rake tmp:cache:clear
3. Start Rails Server
4. Crtl+F5 in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Did you precompile any assets? If so check the public assets folder and remove.

Try clearing  /tmp/cache/assets

Make sure the browser isn't caching the application.css, force refresh etc

Comment: I have cleared everything out and every time I remove the tmp/cache/assets directory, my app re-creates it...

Comment: In development the fingerprint version of every asset is being read