# What is the difference between Rails.cache.clear and rake tmp:cache:clear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

Are the two commands equivalent? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The rake task only clears out files that are stored on the filesystem in `"#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache"`.  Here's the code for that task.

```
namespace :cache do
  # desc "Clears all files and directories in tmp/cache"
  task :clear do
    FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir['tmp/cache/[^.]*'])
  end
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5d85709d346e55827e88f53430a2cbe1e5fb9e/railties/lib/rails/tasks/tmp.rake#L25-L30

`Rails.cache.clear` will do different things depending on your apps setting for `config.cache_store`.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores

If you are using `config.cache_store = :file_store` then `Rails.cache.clear` will be functionally identical to `rake tmp:cache:clear`.  However, if you're using some other `cache_store`, like `:memory_store` or `:mem_cache_store`, then only `Rails.cache.clear` will clear your app cache.  In that case `rake tmp:cache:clear` will just try to remove files from `"#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache"` but probably won't actually do anything since nothing is probably being cached on the filesystem.

Comment: When we changed the cache store to :mem_cache_store, I noticed that Rails.cache.clear started clearing all user sessions as well, logging out all users. Is that the intended behavior? Is there any way to clear the cache without touching the sessions? (We are upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4)