# Why this javascript is not working in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I am clicking `back button` from browser it is showing the outdated value from database. I tried to use following code but it's not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("I am an alert box!");
   });
</script>
```

How to refresh the page or get updated value when users click on back button of browser?

Comment: This post should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: take a look at history.js: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: AFAIK: Normally, browser back and forward buttons refreshes the page (it downloads new version of content from server), unless your new data is  injectected to the dom (via ajax) after page load. In this case, you can manipulate browser history stack (via history.js), and control yourself what data to retrieve on back button click (using the same AJAX  again). I think the above code is not enough.

Comment: What is the platform of your application (Asp.Net Webforms, Asp.Net MVC or php..)?

Comment: @PalaniKumar It's a ruby on rails platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the integration of `jquery` and the code. `Rails` project comes with [TurboLink](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/28-introducing-turbolinks-for-rails-4-0) which have some conflicts with `jquery`. One of the possible solution is to remove `turbolink` from the project (remove it from `application.rb`) and use [Jquery-Turbolink](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

This will allow to use `jquery` inbuilt functions like I had in my question.

Please update the answer or add comment for other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Asp.Net Webforms:**

In Page Load (or) if you want all pages then put on Master Page Load

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

**Asp.Net MVC:**

Add this attribute in Action or Controller

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

Or

If you want disable cache for all views then add the below in Filter Config

```
filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute{VaryByParam = "*",Duration = 0,NoStore = true});
```

**Edit:** I noticed, in comment you mentioned you are using ruby on rail. I am not familiar with that, but the logic is server need to send an header to the browser for "do not cache that page". So you can find some answers here [Ruby on Rails: Clear a cached page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462889/ruby-on-rails-clear-a-cached-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash to determine if it has already been refreshed, to ensure it happens just once:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `onload` function is not working on clicking back button

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?